# docker container python subprocess.Popen php5.6 script is it possible to execute?

Tags: php, python, docker, subprocess, containers

I'm trying to dockerize my python app locally. The app works perfectly when I start in in terminal (Linux mint 19.1). The app has some outputs from the app-shell. First one is connecting with mysql server. Another one is calling python subprocess lib..

proxiScript = 'php5.6 -V'

subprocess.Popen(proxiScript, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

When I create a docker image, at first, I had problem with connecting to mysql [ I solve it with docker run --net host image_name ].

The second problem is.. 
    `/bin/sh: 1: php5.6: not found`

Is there a way to build a standalone image where I'll include all of the needs I'm using in my project.. Maybe I could use host terminal, to making my image successfull ?

Thank you ..

### FROM app ->

```
`
proxiScript = "php5.6 -v "
proc=subprocess.Popen(proxiScript, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`
```

### Dockerfile

`FROM python:3.7-slim
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY . /app
    RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
    EXPOSE 80
    CMD ["python", "test.py"]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add environment path like the following(example, use the ones appropriate for your case):

```
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64
ENV PATH /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Shouldn't you be using an php5 image instead?

Are you sure that you have everything that you need on that python:3.7-slim image?

What are our requirements.txt?

From what I saw on this image, this is a debian 9 with no php5 package installed

You may build your own image and use it like this:

Dockerfile:
    FROM alpine:3.5

```
ENV http_proxy http://proxyapps.gsnet.corp:80
ENV https_proxy https://proxyapps.gsnet.corp:80

RUN apk add --update \
    python \
    python-dev \
    py-pip \
    build-base \
    php5
```

Running this container on interactive mode you may get this:

```
docker run -ti "yourimage"
/ # /usr/bin/php5 -v
PHP 5.6.38 (cli) (built: Oct  1 2018 14:20:42) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

/ # /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.15
```

Comment: Added ENV PATH $PATH (from terminal) but error
`docker run --net host image_name 

/bin/sh: 1: php5.6: not found`
Still occured ..

Comment: updated my answer with a Dockerfile example that my provide functionality that you may need, did not add pip install, leave that to you